# How to write different items of a python list in different Python files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python list as,

```
list1=['data','data and new data','string can be split','words']
```

here elements of list may be of any length and list also may contain any number of elements. 
I want to write them in separate python files, like 
file1 would contain 'data',
file2 would contain 'data and new data' 
file3 would contain 'string can be split'
...
...
like that.

The names of the files would also be created online as the code runs, and preferably not from the data trying to write into the file. 
If anyone may kindly suggest how may I do it?

I am using Python2.7.11 on MS-Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through it with `enumerate()` to get a number (to use in each filename) associated with each element in `list1`:

```
for num,content in enumerate(list1):
    with open('file{}'.format(num+1), 'w') as output:
        output.write(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

for i, item in enumerate(data):
    with open("file%d" % i, 'w') as f:
        f.write(item)
```

Is a quick solution.

*Note: i starts at 0, so your first file will be named 'file0'*

Comment: I would add `f.close(item)` to achieve the process.

Comment: @wiltomap - Two things wrong with that: `with` automatically closes the file at the end of the block without an explicit `close()`, and `close()` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: OK @TigerhawkT3! Didn't know that... Thanks for the comment!